# WebContent folder does not exist, webapp instead

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, web, eclipse-jee

I'm taking the following course right now: "Develop websites with Java EE".
I encounter a problem when creating the Dynamic Web Project because instead of having a WebContent folder like on all the tutorials I've seen, I get a src/main folder...
What should I do to be able to have a WebContent folder

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide specific information about that attempt. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please read [ask] and its linked resources. Could you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Eclipse for some reason replaced WebContent with webapp folder.
It is basically a replacement for it, but if you really want WebContent you can download 2017 version.
Here is the one that I have
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Version: Oxygen.1a Release (4.7.1a)
Build id: 20171005-1200

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/oxygen/1a

https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/oxygen/1a/eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64.zip

After this version WebContent is replaced with webapp

Here is also a picture of the project structure if you have an eclipse that creates webapp or WebContent, as you can see it is basically a replacement to make it look more like maven structure.

[image]

Comment: Please do not install an older version as a solution. You can swap folders using the **Deployment Assembly** property page.

Answer (score 0):

"WebContent" was replaced to form a layout more easily transitioned to building a `.war` file with headless tools like Gradle and Maven. No one should be deploying to a production environment from their IDE. "WebContent" was also fairly unique to Eclipse's Web Tools. There's nothing special about it.

You don't need an older version, only to enter a different value when the New Dynamic Web Project wizard asks you what you want to use as your Content Directory on the third page of the wizard (**if** you don't want to use the new default):

[image: Page 3 in the New Dynamic Web Project wizard]

Comment: How do you reverse thing if you only noticed this that there is no longer a Web Content but I'd need a Web Content to follow thru a tutorial ?

Comment: @KarenGoh Create your WebContent directory, and use the project's **Deployment Assembly** property page to designate it as a folder that deploys to '/'.

Comment: Tks but i found out Jakarata ee is really what I need since i am using java 17 so there is no way to follow that tutorial wholesale. Tks for your reply though.